# How to display error message on model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I need to display error message on model in rails,

my coding on model is like this,

```
if my_address.valid?
  # I need here the validation error.
   return nil
end
```

I used errors.add("Invalid address") but it is not working

please help to solve this problem ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at how scaffolds (`script/generate scaffold my_model`) displays validation errors.

Here's a short summary:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])

  if @post.save # .save checks .valid?
    # Do stuff on successful save
  else
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
```

In the "new" view, you'll use `@post.errors`, most likely with `<%= error_messages_for :post %>`.

Answer (score 3):

You will be able to access the errors via object.errors, i.e. for your case my_address.errors. It will return Error objects, you can check up on it here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html

Comment: To further clarify, you can access the errors for a given attribute with `object.errors.on(:attr)' which will return the error message(s)